# How to get the Role's Names for each user in a list?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I am trying to populate a RoleList which will have the Names of the Roles for each user. I am having trouble with the query part.

I have 2 tables, **IdentityUserRole** table which has *UserId* and *RoleId*, and then **IdentityRoles** table which has the *RoleId*, and the role's *Name*.

This is what I have so far, and it is giving me multiple issues.

```
public static IEnumerable<string> GetRolesByUserId(string userId)
{
    ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

    return db.Set<IdentityUserRole>().Where(r => r.UserId.Contains(userId)).Select(x => x.RoleId);
}
```

I would eventually call the `GetRolesByUserId` in this list.

```
private async Task<IEnumerable<UserViewModel>> GetUserData(ApplicationDbContext db)
{
  var users = db.Users;
  var list = await GetUsers(db, users);

var vmlist = list.Select(item => new UserViewModel()
{
    ID = item.ID,
    Username = item.Username,
    FirstName = item.FirstName,
    LastName = item.LastName,
    Email = item.Email,
    TaxID = item.TaxID,
    TaxIdHash = item.TaxIdHash,
    IV = item.IV,
    TaxIDEncrypted = item.TaxIDEncrypted,
    Active = item.Active,
    RoleList = GetRolesByUserId(item.ID),
    Roles = "",//string.Join(",", GetRolesByUserId(item.ID)).ToArray(),
    IsActive = item.IsActive,
    Status = item.Status
});
```

The UserViewModel has the RoleList as

```
public List<string> RoleList { get; set; }
```

I am fairly new to c# querying and have been trying to solve this issue for the past 3 days. If someone can please assist me in this issue, please. Thank you.

Comment: You can perform an `INNER JOIN` between your IdentityUserRole table and your IdentityRoles table.  You want to join on the RoleId field.  Here's some documentation on LINQ joins: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311040.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the query part, you need something like the following:

```
public static List<string> GetRolesByUserId(string userId)
{
    var db = new ApplicationDbContext();

    var userRoles = from identityUserRole in db.Set<IdentityUserRole>
                    join identityRole in db.Set<IdentityRoles>
                    on identityUserRole.RoleId equals identityRole.RoleId
                    where identityUserRole.UserId == userId
                    select identityRole.Name;

    return userRoles.ToList();
}
```

The above is another syntax to declare a LINQ query and it is called *query syntax*, while the syntax you have used is called *fluent syntax*. At the end the compiler would transform a query written in *query syntax* into an equivalent query written in *fluent syntax*. The reason why I used the *query syntax* here is the fact that I think that in this particular case the query is more readable than if it had been written in *fluent syntax*.

For the record the equivalent query in *fluent syntax* is the following:

```
var userRoles = db.Set<IdentityUserRole>
                  .Join(db.Set<IdentityRoles>,
                        identityUserRole => identityUserRole.RoleId,
                        identityRole => identityRole.RoleId
                        (identityUserRole, identityRole) => { identityRole. Name })
                  .Where(x=>x.UserId == userId)
                  .ToList();
```

Regarding the `Roles` and `RolesList` now I have the following comments.

Since `Roles` can be computed directly from `RoleList` I would suggest you create a property with only a getter, like below:

```
public string Roles 
{
    get 
    { 
        if(RoleList == null || RoleList.Count == 0)
        {
            return null;
        }
        return string.Join(",", RoleList);
    }
}
```

Comment: When I run it, I get an error in the console saying DbQuery<string>' does not contain a definition for 'ToList'.

Comment: What "it" are you running exactly?

Comment: @Christos When I do ToList() in RoleList = GetRolesByUserId(item.ID).ToList();, I get this error message, Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery<string>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>'. And I am not able to call the Roles from the UserViewModel, because it is getter. It is showing "it is read only".

Comment: @Truecolor There are two options. 1) Change the return type of your method to `List<string>` and call `ToList`, before you return 2) Change the type of the method to `IQueryable<string>` and call `ToList` after the method call. Please tyr the update and let me know. Regarding that you can't call the `Roles` from the `UserViewModel` I don't get you. Since `Roles` is a public property of your model why you are not able. Probably I miss something here. Thanks

Comment: I changed both my method type and the RoleList type in`UserViewModel` to `IQueryable<string>` and it worked. And for the `Roles`, I called it in my creating the table Grid method as I didn't know how to set it in my list.   Thank you for all the help. Really appreciate it.

Comment: @Truecolor You are very welcome ! I am glad that I helped.